# imagemagick composite add watermark to pdf and quality

Tags: php, pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript

I need to add watermark in pdf, I found 2 solutions-with ghostscript and imagemagick composite. ghostscript with watermark can't call from command line so I use command composite

`composite -quality 100 -gravity NorthEast -density 400 -dissolve 80% -size 50x30 -geometry +100+20 watermark.png file.pdf file.pdf`

the problem is poor quality of result in pdf. If using image instead pdf quality is ok.

Any ideas?

Comment: You are going to have to be much more specific. What **exactly** do you mean by 'poor quality' ? Have you checked the intermediate files to see where the degradation occurs ? Please post an example input file so we can look at it, and ideally an example output file. Investigate what ImageMagick is actually doing and what the Ghostscript command line(s) are, possibly there is something silly being done there.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure exactly what you are hoping for, but you need to be more careful about the ordering of your parameters. Remember there are two (actually three or more) main types of parameter with ImageMagick:

- There are **settings** (like `-quality`, `-density` and `-gravity`) which are remembered till the end of processing. You may as well put all these at the start of your command and get them out of the way generally.
- There are **operators** (like `-resize`, `-crop`, `-sharpen`) which act immediately on all the currently loaded images.

I think the problem in your command is that you have the images *after* the operators you want to apply instead of *before* and that your `-size` isn't resizing anything - it is just setting the size for any canvases your later create - except that you don't:

```
composite -quality 100 -gravity NorthEast -density 400 -dissolve 80% watermark.png -resize 50x30 -geometry +100+20 file.pdf file.pdf
```